# a question between the first category set and closed proper subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, baire-category

Assume $X$ is a complete norm space with $\mathbb{dim}~X=+\infty$, $E\subset X$ is a proper closed subspace.

On one hand, I have known $E$ is a nowhere dense set, because any proper closed subspace of a norm space is a nowhere set.(then $E$ is the first category set ?)

On the other hand, $X$ is complete, so $E$ is also a complete norm space. From the Baire Category Theorem, $E$ is the second category set.

Why is there a contradiction? Am I wrong in my thinking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$E$ is of first category **in $X$** but of second category in itself.

Note also that $\{0\}$ is of first category in $\mathbb  R$ but of  second category in itself; there are no non-empty nowhere dense subsets of $\{0\}$ in the subspace topology, so it is not a countable union of nowhere dense subsets.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I ignore it.